# Vue, webpack template deployment issue

Tags: deployment, webpack, vue.js

I am working on a project at the moment and it's nearly completed but i have problem about the deployment process. We have Laravel + MySQL backend, Vue2 front end and i am using webpack-simple template.

I have run "npm run build" command and have the dist folder. Should i put this build.js file into the Laravel project?

So my question is simply what should i do after i compile the project with webpack.

I couldn't find anything useful on the web, anyone can maybe give link or general info about the process.

Comment: Every web server has a public folder that is served to the client. Find this folder and copy into it everything in the dist folder